# The objects act like groups

Tags: edit-mode

[image]

There is a random circle when I rotate, resize, or grab, and then if I do any of those things, they act like a group. They are not a group. Does anyone know what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

You have *Proportional Editing* enabled - the blue button with this circular symbol at the top. The circle that appears is not random, it shows the size of the influence radius up to where your translations have an effect on surrounding vertices that are not selected. You can change the size with the scroll wheel. To deactivate *Proportional Editing*, just click on the blue button or press <kbd>O</kbd>.

[image: proportional editing]